# Legend with labels besides seafile heatmap

Tags: python, plot, legend, heatmap, seaborn

I have the following code:

```
from string import letters
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(style="white")

# Compute the correlation matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
corr = df.corr()

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=.3,
            square=True, #xticklabels=5, #yticklabels=5,
            linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5}, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

How is it possible to place an additional legend to the right of the plot that says thinks like:

```
A: This is my first label
B: ...
C: ...
D: ...
```

I would also like to have a label for the correlation bar that simply says 'Correlation'. The data is of course not real data.

Answer (score 1):

About your first question, here is what I managed to do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

sns.set(style="white")

cols = list('ABCD')
# Compute the correlation matrix
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=cols)
corr = df.corr()

# Generate a mask for the upper triangle
mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=.3,
            square=True, #xticklabels=5, #yticklabels=5,
            linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5}, ax=ax)
pseudo_lines = []
strs = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth']
for c, s in zip(cols, strs):
    line = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='blue',
        marker=r"${}:.This.is.my.{}.label$".format(c, s),
        markersize=170, linestyle = 'None')
    pseudo_lines.append(line)
plt.legend(handles=pseudo_lines, labelspacing=2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. I will leave this question open for some time, maybe someone has also a solution for the correlation bar. Thank you again!